# Troubles with Zend Rest Client when trying to call a Web Service developed in ASP and sending a parameter as array

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework

I have this call to a Web Service that is developed with ASP:

```
$endpoint = Zend_Registry::get('config')->endpoint->services->myService;

$client = new Zend_Rest_Client($endpoint);
$client->userId($adminUserId);
$client->otherIds($otherIds);

$result = $client->get();
```

But when I try to call the service the parameter 'otherIds' is not been taken by the WS.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the first called function apparently (as I grok from the source code) is chosen for the "method" parameter. The Zend REST server seems to take this format. I suggest for other servers to feed a dummy method to the client, so the first call should be

```
$client->Dummy();
```

After that, the arguments are set.